# Alternative to heap allocated strings in C (with long lifetimes)

Tags: c, c-strings

Is it possible to use "temporary string objects" in a C program?

For example, I have a reasonably large array of char * objects (part of a struct), which are currently using heap allocated memory.  I have an opportunity to reduce my program's memory usage, since most of these names can be determined without using an explicit character array (although not all of them can).

In C++, I'd simply create an API that returns a std::string object (by value) and be done with it.  In C, I can come up with no solutions that I'm thrilled about.  Advice?

---

Here's some code, as requeted:

```
struct FOO {
    char *name;
    ...
 };

extern FOO* global_foo_array; /* in .h file */

void setup_foo(void) {
    int i;
    global_foo_array = (FOO*) malloc ( get_num_foo() * sizeof(FOO) );

    for (i = 0; i < get_num_foo_with_complex_name(); ++i) {
        global_foo_array.name[i] = malloc ( ... );
    }

    for (i = get_num_foo_with_complex_name(); i < get_num_foo(); ++i) {
        char buf[100];
        sprintf( buf, "foo #%d", i );
        global_foo_array[i].name = strdup( buf );
    }
}
```

get_num_foo() is approximately 100-1000x larger than get_num_foo_with_complex_name().  The program, for the most part, treats 'global_foo_array[].name' as read-only.

I see a non-negligible memory savings here and am wondering what's the best way to achieve that savings, balancing the human investment.

Comment: "without using an explicit character array" - do you mean using a string literal instead?  The memory has to come from somewhere.  Can you post a bit of code to provide context - maybe ideal client code?

Comment: When you return a `std::string` object, you still allocate on the heap (unless for extremely short strings, in the case your STL uses SSO). As Scott Jones says, the memory has to come from somewhere

Comment: Check out the `Atom` type in [C Interfaces and Implementations](http://www.amazon.com/Interfaces-Implementations-Techniques-Creating-Reusable/dp/0201498413) by D R Hanson.  This allows you to have just one copy of each string in the program, but requires the discipline of not modifying strings (rather, you create a new `Atom` to hold the new string, which might be the same as an existing `Atom`).

Comment: What is the problem with creating an API that returns `char *` pointers? Apart from the lack of protection w.r.t. write attempts, that is?

Comment: If on C99 or hight, why not use VLAs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?

Comment: Why would you expect using `std::string` to reduce the memory usage here?  It allocates space on the heap for strings and has the disadvantage that the same string might be allocated multiple times, so would generally use more memory, not less.  Unless most of the "foo" names are never used, in which case you'd be better creating them on demand as needed rather than all at once on startup.

Comment: It's not that std::string will reduce memory if all FOO objects are alive simultaneously...but, most callers will either iterate through all '.name' fields and then immediately move on.  I can achieve the desired functionality without storing most names persistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't actually need all the strings, the obvious choice would be to create them on demand:

```
struct FOO {
    char *name;
    ...
};

static FOO* global_foo_array; /* NOT in .h file */

void setup_foo(void) {
    int i;
    global_foo_array = (FOO*) malloc ( get_num_foo() * sizeof(FOO) );
    memset(global_foo_array, 0, get_num_foo() * sizeof(FOO) );
}

FOO *get_foo(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > get_num_foo())
        return 0;
    if (!global_foo_array[i].name) {
        if (i < get_num_foo_with_complex_name()) {
            global_foo_array.name[i] = malloc ( ... );
        } else {
            char buf[32];
            sprintf( buf, "foo #%d", i );
            global_foo_array[i].name = strdup( buf );
        }
    }
    return &global_foo_array[i];
}
```

This still wastes space for all the `FOO` objects you don't need.  If those are large, it might be better to have `static FOO **global_foo_array` (an extra level of indirection), and allocate those on demand too.

Comment: This, of course, is legacy code that I'm working with...I hate, hate, hate global variables with a passion.